# How does Angular's data-binding's interpolation work?

Tags: angular

This is more about internals of Angular. When I put something in between "{{xyz.abc}}" how does it work? How come that I see the value of that property, not just xyz.abc in between two braces?

Answer (score 0):

> {{ }} this is called String Interpolation.

whenever angular detect this pattern in the template, **it will execute the expression inside 
 {{ expression }}.**

when Angular change detection system run, it will **re Evaluate** the expression inside {{ expression }}

this is called **One-Way Data-Binding** .

you use it when you want to display a dynamic data from typeScript code into your template.

learn more: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data.